# Cordova - android error when building

Tags: android, cordova

This is my first experience in cordova. I created the helloworld project and installed the android platform correctly. When I tried to build the project by `cordova build android`, it shows this error message.

```
Running command: /home/menaka/hello/platforms/android/cordova/build 
[Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.]
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /home/menaka/hello/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /home/menaka/hello/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

But I have successfully set the `ANDROID_HOME` variable and `PATH`.

```
menaka@menaka-X550LC:~/hello$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/Extra/Softwares/Android/Sdk/
```

So, what would be the reason for this?

Comment: *But I have successfully set the ANDROID_HOME variable and PATH.* how do you know it was successful? How did you verify?

Comment: I used echo $ANDROID_HOME and it worked fine. Also I 'android' command executed the SDK Manager.

Comment: Restarting terminal might help (unless its not in your bashrc

Comment: I tried but it did not worked. :-(

Comment: in the path you need $ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools and $ANDROID_HOME/tools what did you add? (you write about $ANDROID_HOME, but don't say what you put in the path)

Comment: ANDROID_HOME=/Extra/Softwares/Android/Sdk/ and PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools